# Vue: How to find out dependencies needed for a build engine on a CI platform?

Tags: vue.js, npm, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, laravel-mix

I have a Vue app built that requires me to build the assets from my machine each time updates are made.  Another developer asked me let them know the dependencies so that they set up a build engine on Circle CI.  Does that mean the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` listed in `package.json`?  Some of those I don't remember manually installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what your colleague is asking for without talking to them directly, but for cloud-based continuous integration systems, you usually need to know what the system prerequisites are in order to build. The stuff that's in package.json is the easy bit, as long as you have a "build" command in your package.json "scripts" section.

As an example, I have a package.json that looks roughly like this:

```
"build": "yarn build:umd & yarn build:es & yarn build:unpkg",
"build:umd": "rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format umd --file dist/honeybadger-vue.umd.js",
"build:es": "rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format es --file dist/honeybadger-vue.esm.js",
"build:unpkg": "rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format iife --file dist/honeybadger-vue.js",
"build:unpkg-minify": "rollup MINIFY=true --config build/rollup.config.js --format iife --file dist/honeybadger-vue.min.js",
```

However, for the continuous integration setup, I need to tell the CI system what I need in order to run those commands. Those are likely the dependencies your colleague is asking about.

For example, I use Travis rather than Circle CI, but I need to specify which versions of Node I need to run tests on, which external dependencies I might need in order to build the library and to run tests. That could be libraries like ImageMagick, headless Chrome, maybe a database client for some use cases. I also need to know what commands need to be run to run the build (travis makes a reasonable assumption once you tell it that the language is node_js; I would expect Circle CI to be similar).

In my particular Travis setup, I have a config file in the project called .travis.yml that tells Travis everything it needs to know, like this:

```
dist: trusty
language: node_js
node_js:
   - 8
   - 10
   - 11
sudo: false
addons:
  chrome: stable
before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start
before_install:
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
```

This lists the versions of Node I want to test with, a list of pre-build commands, and some addons I need. I could just as easily add things with the OS package manager if I needed to.

Basically, I presume your developer counterpart is looking for enough information to make sure it's possible to build the library on someone else's machine. That's almost certainly what they mean by "dependencies", as your package file will contain sufficient information to reference any of the dependencies that Node can handle itself.

Comment: damn, this was a fantastic answer!  Thanks so much!!